# C# Selenium Headless Chrome Driver is not executing javascript from the website

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I'm trying to scrape javascript generated html objects from a website. I've tried many different libraries and I found out that selenium has everything i need.

I've tried to run the driver without being in headless mode, and it WORKS,
but that's not what I need. I need a background task to keep the user interface as clean as possible.

```
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-startup-window");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=" + Settings.globalUserAgent);
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--log-level=3");

        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;

        using(var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions))
        {
            driver.Url = "https://example.com";

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/otherpage");
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            var element = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("sub-conv-fu")));

            string source = driver.PageSource;

            if (source.Contains("some string:"))
            {
                File.WriteAllText("test.txt", source);
            } else
            {
                File.WriteAllText("test.txt", source);
                return "Error";
            }

        }
        return "";
```

This line of code contains a variable which I want to get. It's loaded using javascript

```
var element = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("sub-conv-fu")));
```

It is working if I remove the "--headless" tag.

Comment: What is error/message you are getting while running in headless mode?

Comment: Hello, i just get a Timeout Exception, because of this line: var element = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("sub-conv-fu")));